# Problema, estructura de datos, multilistas

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos

Hola tengo un código que se supone son multilistas, en mi caso particular se listan oficinas y empleados

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

struct empleado
{ 
  int codigo;
  float sueldo;
  string cargo;
  string nombre;
  empleado *ap_emp; 
}*emp; 

struct oficina
{ 
  int codigo;
  string nombre;
  oficina *ap_o;
  empleado *ap_e;
  
}*cola,*cab,*nuevo,*busca1,*busca2;

void capturar(void);
void menu_of(void);
void menu_emp(void);
void capturar_of(void);
void listar_of (void);
void borrar_of (void);
```

El profesor nos indica que se debe adicionar a la estructura empleado, la variable sueldo, siguiente a esto y es donde tengo el problema supongo en lógica es "Generar un reporte (listado) donde muestre el sueldo pagado por oficina.
Mi pregunta es y puede que la respuesta sea sencilla, solo seria adicionar la variable sueldo al listar_of?
La otra idea que tengo seria crear el listado de empleados, añadirle la variable sueldo a ese listar pero no sabria como representar el total de los sueldos por oficina

Comment: Cabe aclarar que esos voids ya estan hechos solo no añado el codigo pues seria mas extenso.

Answer (score 0):

Segun entiendo a tu problema y lo que te dijo el profesor es que quiere que el sueldo se comporte como una lista encadenada, pq digo esto es pq observo que la variable sueldo ya esta en la estructura empleado.

Por lo que a la hora de ponerla como lista encadenada tendras que replicar todas los procedimiento tal y como haces con empleado y oficina.

La lista encadenada que tienes es similar a esta imagen:

[image: lista encadenada]